# SQL, Finding Counts of a Group By MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Basically, I have a  MySQL table with comments, which have IDs and dates submitted, and I want users to be able to edit these comments. When a comment is edited, I'd like to create a new entry in the table with the same ID as the comment being edited, but a new date.

So when I'm selecting my list of comments, I want to use SELECT MAX(`DateSubmitted`) ... Group By `ID`, but I'd also like to get a count of the number of IDs that are grouped for each one, so I know how many times a comment has been edited.

I think it should be something like this:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(1) as "Number of edits"
FROM comments
GROUP BY ID;
```

Merged with:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(`DateSubmitted`), Comment
FROM comments
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the latest comment text as well as the date edited and count:

```
SELECT a.ID, a. MaxDateSubmitted, a.NumComments, b.Comment
(SELECT ID, 
        MAX(`DateSubmitted`) as "MaxDateSubmitted", 
        COUNT('ID') as "NumComments"
FROM comments
GROUP BY ID) a
INNER JOIN comments b ON a.ID = b.ID and b.DateSubmitted = a.MaxDateSubmitted;
```

**Note**: this assumes no two edits have exactly the same date and time (down to the precision of the time portion). But in this case, I think this is a valid assumption.

If you just want the latest edit date and count:

```
 SELECT ID, 
        MAX(`DateSubmitted`) as "MaxDateSubmitted", 
        COUNT('ID') as "NumComments"
 FROM comments
 GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Wait a minute, since the IDs will be the same, are you certain that the comment selected in the top query will be the one that corresponds to the latest date?

Comment: apologies, I knew there was something bugging me about this query. Thanks to @am05mhz who spotted I needed to add the date join condition.

Comment: also to be considered, if **DateSubmitted** only contains date data, this query would fail, but if **DateSubmitted** is TIMESTAMP, then it would be fine

Comment: isn't that what I said in my note? "this assumes no two edits have exactly the same date and time"

Comment: yeah, it basically the same, but there are some people that store date values without the time, i'm just encouraging to use TIMESTAMP instead

Comment: It's using a DateTime field, so that shouldn't be an issue, thanks for the answer, that looks perfect!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) as "Number of edits", MAX(`DateSubmitted`)
FROM comments
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I should've made it clearer that I also wanted the latest comment